# Return value with VLOOKUP that has three search criteria - two values and one blank cell

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

Based on the Columns A AND B, (which are duplicates), I'd like to  return the value in Column D IF Column C is blank
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider adding these two columns!

ColE: It will join both columns and B (in E2)...

> =ARRAYFORMULA(CONCAT(A2:A,B2:B))

ColF: ... in order to count them and find the duplicates in (F2)

> =byrow(E2:E,lambda(each,IF(each="","",COUNTIF(E2:E,each))))

ColH: This query will return A,B and D columns where C is blank and it's a duplicate (ColF > 1)

> =query(A:F,"SELECT A,B,D where F > 1 AND C is null")

You can see it in action in this sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fu8Z38IVj46fF1uXABZkX9s06vxF-UU9TkO9Bs9KtW4/edit?usp=sharing

I've tried to do it all in one cell, but calculations took forever

[image]

Comment: I know it says I'm not supposed to say thanks on these comments, but I really appreciate your help. Clever yet light workaround, I'm going to use this for other things I've overcomplicated!

Comment: Well, I'm glad it worked! Good luck with your projects!!